# Counting users with passing score

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the total users who have a passing scores.

```php
$count = 0;
$sel = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT score from user_table");
if ($sel >= "10") {
    $count += 1;
    echo $count;
} else {
    $count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve, perhaps with an example.

Comment: I am trying to get the total user who got passing score inside my database but it seems it can't get the total of passing user, sorry.

Comment: the "score" is the column, I am trying to get the passing scores in that column then total of user who passed

Answer (score 1):

if your condition to pass is `score>= 10`, and score is a column representing the score and user_name is a column representing the user, then your SQL is:

```
SELECT `user_name` FROM `user_table` WHERE `score` >= 10
```

Translated to PHP it would be something like :

#### The simple solution

```php
$conn = .....
// you select all information about the users who passed
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_table` WHERE `score` >= 10";
// your query
$qry = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
// you count the matched rows
$sel = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
```

#### Using "COUNT"

```php
$conn = .....
// this counts the users who passed and assign the value to a virtual column called sel
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`user_name`) AS `sel` FROM `user_table` WHERE `score` >= 10";
// this is your query
$qry = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
// now you fetch the result as a array (with only one column)
$arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
// your variable sel
$sel = $arr['sel'];
```

there are also other solutions, but I considered this where for beginners
have fun :)

Comment: thank you so much. I'm having errors but I got an idea because of that, I really appreciate it ^^

Comment: what kind of errors?

Comment: thank you so much for the example, I got an idea because of that and it worked ^^